# to_dict() creates brackets around values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to create default dictionary from my pandas DataFrame, but to_dict() method creates unwanted square brackets around values of the columns i want to write. The example code is as follows:

```
# Create DF
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 'letters': ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')})

# Create dictionary from the DF
my_dict = my_df.set_index('numbers').T.to_dict('list')

# Create collections dictionary
my_collections_dict = collections.defaultdict(int, my_dict)
```

results in:

```
defaultdict(int, {1: ['a'], 2: ['b'], 3: ['c'], 4: ['d'], 5: ['e']})
```

what i want is:

```
defaultdict(int, {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'})
```

how to obtain 'pure' column values?

Comment: you are passing a `dict` to the `defaultdict` constructor, so it will return the equivalent defaultdict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to transpose your frame, you can instead select your column and do:

```
my_dict = my_df.set_index('numbers')['letters'].to_dict()
```

---

if you have multiple columns you want to use in your dictionary, it'll take an extra line but you can use:

```
my_dict = my_df.set_index('numbers').to_dict(orient='index')
my_dict = {k: list(v.values()) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem even in a more simpler and faster way. How would it work if I have more than one column? e.x: `pd.DataFrame({'numbers': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 'letters': ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), 'other_letters': ('f', 'g', 'h', 'j', ''k)})`

Comment: @IamNik what would your desired output be from the multiple columns?

Comment: i would like to get similar result that will be obtained by the approach from my question: `defaultdict(int, {1: ['a', 'f'], 2: ['b', 'g'], ...`

Answer (score 1):

It's because you specify `to_dict('list')` -> this way entries will be returned as lists (which is why they are shown in `[]`.

Try using `records` instead:

```
# Create DF
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 'letters': ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')})

# Create dictionary from the DF
my_dict = my_df.set_index('numbers').T.to_dict('records')

# Create collections dictionary
my_collections_dict = collections.defaultdict(int, my_dict)
```

Output from the second line:

`[{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}]`

Comment: I dont know why but i get following error `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required`

Comment: what happens if you skip transposition (T in the second line)?

Comment: i dont think that its transposition - `my_dict` id successfully created. The problem is in `defaultdict()` - it doesnt want to create default dictionary from `my_dict`. Good part is - `my_dict` now, indeed, doesnt have brackets :)

Comment: Am trying to get rid of the square brackets around the dictionary [] so I can loop - for k,v in my_dict.iteritem() through them - any ideas? I can convert to str() and strip (.replace) because iteritem() won't work